# pyqt4: AttributeError: 'QPlainTextEdit' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, error-handling, pyqt4

I'm aware that there are similar problems to mine but I tried those solutions and they don't work.

I have text field:

```
self.tMail = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
self.tMail.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 270, 451, 75))
self.tMail.setAccessibleName(_fromUtf8(""))
self.tMail.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
self.tMail.setPlainText(_fromUtf8(""))
self.tMail.setOverwriteMode(False)
self.tMail.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tMail"))
```

And i want to add them to the variable string by:

```
def handleButton(self):
    timeString = self.tCzas.text()
    mailString = self.tMail.text()
    IDString = self.tID.text()
    teamString = self.tTeam.text()
    print(timeString)
    print(mailString)
    print(IDString)
    print(teamString)`
```

also I tried:

`mailString = self.tMail.plainText()`

and I always get an error:
`AttributeError: 'QPlainTextEdit' object has no attribute '...'`

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QPlainTextEdit` doesn't have a `text()` function. try  using the `toPlainText()` function:

```
def handleButton(self):
    timeString = self.tCzas.toPlainText()
    mailString = self.tMail.toPlainText()
    IDString = self.tID.toPlainText()
    teamString = self.tTeam.toPlainText()
    print(timeString)
    print(mailString)
    print(IDString)
    print(teamString)
```